# mover a la esquina derecha opciones del _layau de una aplicación web, adjunto imágenes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

hola gente soy bastante nuevo en asp ya he pedido unas ayudas basic as, y quería ver si me ayudaban en esta duda que supongo sera fácil para ustedes.

adjunto imagen para que vean de que hablo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

básicamente mi duda es como puedo mover la opción registro, cerrar sesión y login hasta final de la cabecera del _layau con la propiedad text-end no se mueve solo se deforma entonces quería saber si podrían ayudarme con eso gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como repito estamos en el _layau

Comment: <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">

Comment: muchas gracias, no puedo darte el voto de que tu pregunta me funciono